# Unable To execute Program Due To Conflicting Types for built in function

Tags: c

Whenever I try to compile the program it shows an error conflicting types for function strcat. Please Help

main.c:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "Q2.h"

    main()
    {
         char x[100], y[100];

         gets(x);
         gets(y);

         printf("%s",strcat(x,y));
     }
```

Q2.h:

```
char strcat(char a[100], char b[100])
{
    int i, j;

    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    while (b[j] != '\0')
    {
        a[i] = b[j];
        j++;
        i++;
    }

    return a[100];
}
```

Comment: Write down the exact error message. It should include a hint regarding the problematic line.

Comment: Could you possibly indent your code in a way that makes it more readable? Also, you usually do not define functions in headers, you only declare them there.

Comment: 2 [Warning] conflicting types for built-in function 'strcat'

Comment: Yeah! I'll be careful next time!

Comment: @NilayKapadia Try compiling with `-fno-builtin` option to gcc.

Comment: `char strcat` : wrong return type. `return a[100];` : wrong return value. `int i, j;` : not initialize. `a`(after `strcat`) is no guarantee that ends with NUL.

Comment: Note that `a[100]` is an out-of-bounds access. This is not causing your problem here but it will cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your error message is pretty simple to explain: **C doesn't support overloading functions.**

By default, there's a [`strcat()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) accepting two pointers (i.e. `char *strcat(char *dst, char *src)`) that works similar to what you've written.

Depending on your compiler/IDE (e.g. Microsoft Visual Studio), some standard headers or functions might actually be included/defined, even though you didn't explicitly include them.

To fix this problem, either switch to C++ or rename your own function (or try to avoid including *string.h*, if you included it yourself).

Answer (score -1):

In your code include `#include <string.h>`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Comment: Actually The problem statement says that the program should be executed without the string library

Comment: I suspect you're running into difficulties because `strcat` is magic in that it's a "built-in" function with some special properties. Do things work if you call your function something other than `strcat`? (say `my_strcat`)

Comment: Yeah It Removed the error! I renamed it to strconcat and it worked!! Thanks!